# Get Bluebird Promise from async await functions

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await, bluebird, es6-promise

I am looking for a way, with Node v7.6 or above, to get a [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/) Promise (or any non-native promise) when an async function is called.

In the same way I can do:

```js
global.Promise = require('Bluebird'); // Or Q/When
var getResolvedPromise = () => Promise.resolve('value');

getResolvedPromise
  .tap(...) // Bluebird method
  .then(...);
```

*See: [May I use global.Promise=require("bluebird")](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/issues/1026)*

I want to be able to do something like:

```js
global.Promise = require('Bluebird'); // Or Q/When
var getResolvedAsyncAwaitPromise = async () => 'value';

getResolvedAsyncAwaitPromise()
  .tap(...) // Error ! Native Promises does not have `.tap(...)`
  .then(...);
```

**I know I can use at any moment something like:**

```js
Bluebird.resolve(getResolvedAsyncAwaitPromise())
  .tap(...);
```

But I was *curious* if there would be a way to change the default Promise returned by `AsyncFunction`. The constructor seems enclosed:

> Note that AsyncFunction is not a global object. It could be obtained by evaluating the following code.
>
> ```js
> Object.getPrototypeOf(async function(){}).constructor
> ```

*[MDN reference on `AsyncFunction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/AsyncFunction)*

If there is no way to change the `AsyncFunction`'s Promise constructor, I would like to know the reasons of this locking.

Thank you !

Comment: No, that's not possible. If it was, that would mean you would globally overwrite the promise implementation, which is a nightmare.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Is there a way to change the default Promise returned by AsyncFunction

No.

> What are the reasons of this locking

The ability to hijack all `async function`s could be a security issue. Also, even where that is no problem, it's still not useful to do this replacement globally. It would affect your entire realm, including all libraries that you are using. They might rely on using native promises. And you cannot use two different promise libraries, although they might be required.

> I want to be able to do something like:
>
> ```
> getResolvedAsyncAwaitPromise().tap(...)
> ```

What you *can* do is to wrap the function at its definition with [`Promise.method`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.method.html):

```
const Bluebird = require('Bluebird');
const getResolvedAsyncAwaitPromise = Bluebird.method(async () => 'value');

getResolvedAsyncAwaitPromise()
.tap(…) // Works!
.then(…);
```

Comment: > `Also, even where that is no problem, it's still not useful to do this replacement globally` — not correct, it is useful because node.js [has very ugly stack traces for async/await calls](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/11865). And if replacement is possible then someone can replace Promise implementation to Bluebird and get nice useful stack traces.