# How to return a Promise as the result of another promise when it is resolved

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

Here a sample code:

```
function getExtendedPromise() {
    const promise = new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve('Hi');
        }, 1000)
    });
    promise.on = () => {
        console.log('on listener called')
    };
    console.log('getExtendedPromise: ', promise);
    return promise;
}

async function callExtendedPromise() {
    await Promise.resolve();
    return Promise.resolve(getExtendedPromise())
}

const promise = callExtendedPromise();
console.log('callExtendedPromise Try: ', promise);
callExtendedPromise().then((result) => {
    console.log('Final Result: ', result)
});
```

Log Results:

```
callExtendedPromise Try:  Promise { <pending> }
getExtendedPromise:  Promise { <pending>, on: [Function] }
getExtendedPromise:  Promise { <pending>, on: [Function] }
Final Result:  Hi
```

As seen from the sample above, when the object is logged inside the getExtendedPromise() function, it has an `on` property. I then wrap it in a `Promise.resolve`, and return it to the caller because I want the caller to get the `Promise` object with the `on` property.

However, when calling `callExtendedPromise()`, I am not able to access that wrapped promise with the `on` property.

How can I get that promise instance with the `on` property?

**`getExtendedPromise()` is the part of a library and not open for modification.**

**P.S.** the choice of the structure of the extended promise is not my choice in the original code, but rather the structure returned from a library.

Comment: in the 'gEP()' at the top, try returning something instead of a resolve . EX return another method (Async) that resolves to an object containing the required property.

Comment: `getExtendedPromise()` is the part of a library and not open for modification.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Bluebird Promise from async await functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44158629/get-bluebird-promise-from-async-await-functions)

Comment: @JoshLee that question and my question are completely different from what I can see.

Comment: `return getExtendedPromise()` will return the promise with added `on` property. if you wrap result of `getExtendedPromise()` in Promise.resolve then you'll get a new promise that resolves or rejects to whatever getExtendedPromise() resolves or rejects to so you loose the `on` property.

Comment: `return getExtendedPromise()` doesn't work either, that's why I wrapped it in `Promise.resolve`

Comment: Sorry, you are correct. The `async` messes up your promise, I guess because it wraps the result in a promise. Removing `async` from `callExtendedPromise` will work but you can't use `await` syntax

Comment: There is very limited utility in decorating promises with an ad-hoc method, because of what you have discovered - it's at best ethereal. 
The real question to ask yourself is how to purge the use of `.on()` from the codebase.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 we tried that, but the even whose data we need to send in response to an API call is emitted as an event in like 3-4 seconds. The actual promise resolution can take upto and over a minute.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a good reason to decorate a promise. There's got to be another way.

Comment: From the docs of the library I'm using, it doesn't seem so: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/callbacks-promises-events.html

Comment: Thank you for the link, I hadn't read that. First thought: looks like an attempt at reintroducing progress notifications, a critique of which is provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32909893/3478010).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, it may not be possible to return an extended `Promise` from an `async` function. (Following taken from [async function on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function))

> ...the return value of an async function is implicitly wrapped in Promise.resolve.

---

If you can modify `callExtendedPromise` and can confine consuming the extended parts (i.e. any call to `on`) to that method, then I'd do that. Alternatively, you could use some sort of returned object (see below). I'd recommend against this in general (though the real root of the issue is trying to extend the individual `Promise` instance and then also use it as a `Promise`, which it sounds like you have no way to adjust), but it should be

```
async function callExtendedPromise() {
    await Promise.resolve();
    return {extendedPromise: getExtendedPromise()};
}

...

const extendedPromise = (await callExtendedPromise()).extendedPromise;
extendedPromise.on(); // 'on listener called'
extendedPromise.then(message => console.log(message)); // 'Hi!'
```

Comment: Any idea of any hack or patch I can do to make this work. I agree that the library returning this structure is weird, but I can't switch to another library.

Comment: @AyushGupta I just edited the question to include a workaround.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I agree it's not a particularly nice solution (and I'll edit to reflect that), but I don't agree with your reasoning: I'm able to call `extendedPromise.then(...)` and have it resolve as expected using this solution.